# MongoDB match documents that contain an array field with ALL elements that match the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

From the MongoDB doc for [`$elementMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

**But how can I match documents that contain an array field with ALL elements that match the query?**

For example I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c83"),
    "sku": "ed-39211",
    "created_at": ISODate("2015-08-11T06:29:29.139+0000"),
    "formats": [{
        "name": "thefile",
        "_id": ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9c"),
        "prices": [{
            "price": 4.49,
            "currency": "GBP",
            "territory": "GB",
            "_id": ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9f")
        }, {
            "price": 6.99,
            "currency": "USD",
            "territory": "US",
            "_id": ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9e")
        }, {
            "price": 6.99,
            "currency": "CHF",
            "territory": "CH",
            "_id": ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9d")
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I need to match all documents that have **all** the `formats.prices.price` > 5

If I use the following query:

```
{ 'formats.prices': { $elemMatch: { price: { $gte: 5 } } } }
```

That document will be matched because there is at least one price > 5

I also tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{ 'formats.prices': { $all: { $elemMatch: {price: { $gte: 0.98 } } } } }
```

Is there a way to exclude that document looking at all prices an not at least one?

Answer (score 5):

Found it! It was easy, just use `$not`operator and check the opposite (< 5):

```
{ 'formats.prices': { $not: { $elemMatch: {price: { $lt: 5 } } } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Aggegation OR MAP REDUCE to achieve it :

**First solution is using Map-Reduce** :

I created a collection called "format" and inserted below data :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c83"),
        "sku" : "ed-39211",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2015-08-11T06:29:29.139Z"),
        "formats" : [
                {
                        "name" : "thefile",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9c"),
                        "prices" : [
                                {
                                        "price" : 4.49,
                                        "currency" : "GBP",
                                        "territory" : "GB",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9f")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "USD",
                                        "territory" : "US",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9e")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "CHF",
                                        "territory" : "CH",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9d")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c84"),
        "sku" : "ed-39211",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2015-08-11T06:29:29.139Z"),
        "formats" : [
                {
                        "name" : "thefile",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9a"),
                        "prices" : [
                                {
                                        "price" : 5.49,
                                        "currency" : "GBP",
                                        "territory" : "GB",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9f")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "USD",
                                        "territory" : "US",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9e")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "CHF",
                                        "territory" : "CH",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9d")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

**Map_reduce :**

```
db.format.mapReduce(
    function()
            {
            var doc  = {"_id" : this._id, "sku" : this.sku, "created_at" : this.created_at, "formats" : this.formats};
            var prices;
            var flag = 0;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < doc.formats.length; i++)
            {
                prices = doc.formats[i].prices
                for ( var j =0 ; j < prices.length; j++)
                {
                    if( prices[j].price < 5)
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if( flag == 1)
                doc.formats.splice(i,1);
            }
                if( doc.formats.length > 0 )
                emit( this._id, doc);
            },
    function(){},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Output :

```
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c84"),
                        "value" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c84"),
                                "sku" : "ed-39211",
                                "created_at" : ISODate("2015-08-11T06:29:29.139Z"),
                                "formats" : [
                                        {
                                                "name" : "thefile",
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9a"),
                                                "prices" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "price" : 5.49,
                                                                "currency" : "GBP",
                                                                "territory" : "GB",
                                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9f")
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "price" : 6.99,
                                                                "currency" : "USD",
                                                                "territory" : "US",
                                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9e")
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "price" : 6.99,
                                                                "currency" : "CHF",
                                                                "territory" : "CH",
                                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9d")
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
```

**Second Solution using Aggregation** :

Using aggregate operators $unwind and $size we can get the required result using below query :

After [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) of "Formats" and "Formats.prices", size of the "Formats.prices" is taken and then a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) on the "prices" is done and again the new size is calculated for "Formats.prices".

If the size  are same then all the "prices" in the "format" field are greater than 5 and the document will be projected.

```
db.format.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$formats" },
{ $project : { _id : 1, sku : 1, created_at : 1, formats : 1, "size" : { $size : "$formats.prices" } } },
{ $unwind: "$formats.prices" },
{ $match: { "formats.prices.price" : { $gt:5 } } },
{ $group: { _id: { "name" : "$formats.name" , "_id" : "$formats._id", "id" : "$_id" }, prices : { $push: "$formats.prices" } , sku: { $first: "$sku" }, created_at : { $first: "$created_at" }, oldsize : { $first: "$size" } } },
{ $project: { _id : 1, prices : 1, sku : 1, created_at : 1, oldsize : 1, newsize : {$size: "$prices" } } },
{ $project: { _id : 1, prices : 1, sku : 1, created_at : 1, cmp_value: { $cmp: ["$oldsize", "$newsize"] } } },
{ $match: { cmp_value:{ $eq:0 } } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id.id" , sku: { $first: "$sku" }, created_at : { $first: "$created_at" }, formats : { $push: { name : "$_id.name", "_id" : "$_id._id", prices: "$prices" } }  } }
                  ]).pretty()
```

Output :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649b8b5fc5b0a2f1c84"),
        "sku" : "ed-39211",
        "created_at" : ISODate("2015-08-11T06:29:29.139Z"),
        "formats" : [
                {
                        "name" : "thefile",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9a"),
                        "prices" : [
                                {
                                        "price" : 5.49,
                                        "currency" : "GBP",
                                        "territory" : "GB",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9f")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "USD",
                                        "territory" : "US",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9e")
                                },
                                {
                                        "price" : 6.99,
                                        "currency" : "CHF",
                                        "territory" : "CH",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("55c99649f2e2d6353348ec9d")
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```